# accessing media manager with different user persmissions

Tags: laravel-5, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I built a plugin to store post image using media finder widget, and I set two roles admin and data-entry, when I'm accessing the backend with admin user I can add posts and images. But when I access the backend with data-entry user and when I click on media finder icon it generates the following error:

> A widget with class name 'ocmediamanager' has not been bound to the
>   controller" on line 513 of /modules/backend/Classes/Controller.php

I searched the net for any hint about this error but no luck.

I'm using October CMS Build: 434

Please advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems you didn't `add proper permission` to `data-entry` role. **To access media** your `role` need `media.manage_media` permission.

You can `add that permission to role` and `media` can be accessible for that user role

> **Go to Settings > Administrators > Manage Roles > Select You Role for update**

Now in permission tab find  **> System** list

There will be permission named : **Upload and manage media contents - images, videos, sounds, documents**

Please **check mark that one as well**

Now your `user with that role` can **access** `media`.

If any further query please comment.